# Using HTML and Javascript I want the solution

Tags: javascript, html

I have two fields permanent address and current address and a checkbox field. I want that if I click on checkbox then the current address field should be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are new to the community and asked for very basic example. From next time onwards, please show us your work before seeking help.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('.js-disableCurrentAddress');
var currentAddr = document.querySelector('.js-currentAddress');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', handleDisable);

function handleDisable() {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    currentAddr.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {
    currentAddr.removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="js-currentAddress" placeholder="current">
<input type="text" class="js-permanentAddress" placeholder="permanent">
<label>
  Disable current address
  <input type="checkbox" class="js-disableCurrentAddress">
</label>
```